# How to make flutter customized text decoration?

Tags: flutter, widget, text-decorations

I have the following widget that is required to be part of a column in my flutter application:
[image]
I tried to make this widget by creating a row then put a text widget inside that row and then search for a text decoration that provide that 2 lines to each side of the text. But i did not found any decoration that provide this shape.  The only decoration that i found is:

```
Text('OR',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 30,
    color: Colors.grey,
    decoration: TextDecoration.underline
  ),
)
```

this will give:
[image]
I also thought about another solution that to make each one of these 2 lines a widget and put the 3 widgets (the 2 lines and the text between them) inside a row.
But I think that flutter provide a more easy solution for this.
Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: I don't think there is a decoration like that at the moment. Your idea of using row will work.

Answer (score 3):

```
Row(
  children:[
    Expanded(
      child: Divider(),
    ),

    Text('OR',
     style: TextStyle(
     fontSize: 30,
     color: Colors.grey,
     ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Divider(),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. That's especially important when there's already an older answer with at least some community support. Under what conditions might your approach be preferred? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Takes advantage of the built-in `Row` and `Divider` widgets:

```
class LineWithTitle extends StatelessWidget {
  const LineWithTitle({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Divider(),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Text('Jhone'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Divider(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```